# inroder_iterator for syntax tree of markargs

Tags: c++, tree, c++14, iterator

### Introduction

It is a spin-off to my compiler creation.

### Problem

Traverse the [`markargs::syntax_tree`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/173125/building-abstract-syntax-tree-for-markargs) in order, e.g. first goes `left_operand`, then `operator`, then `right_operand`.

It can be used to collect statistics, run searches, transform some nodes, copy into `istream`s, etc. In general, it is a good skill to have, in my opinion (although I hate algorithms that are big if-else's). I'm considering moving streaming operator to use this iterator.

### Code

**inorder_iterator_tests.cpp**

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <token.hpp>
#include "syntax_tree.hpp"

void test_one(const std::string& inputline, const std::string& correct_answer)
{
    std::stringstream ss(inputline);
    markargs::syntax_tree tree{std::istream_iterator<markargs::token>(ss), {}};
    std::ostringstream result;

    auto begin = tree.inorder_begin();
    auto end = tree.inorder_end();

    for (; begin != end; ++begin)
    {
        result << begin->payload();
    }

    if (result.str() != correct_answer)
    {
        std::cout << result.str() << '\n';
        throw std::logic_error{"tree was not build correctly for input: "
                               + inputline};
    }
}

void run_tests()
{
    std::ifstream input_file("input.txt");
    std::ifstream answers_file("answers.txt");
    if (!input_file.is_open() || !answers_file.is_open())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error{"either input or answers file cannot be opened"};
    }

    std::string inputline;
    std::string correct_answer;

    std::cout << "starting inorder iterator tests ...\n";
    unsigned int counter = 1;
    while (std::getline(input_file, inputline) && std::getline(answers_file, correct_answer))
    {
        std::cout << "running test #" << counter << '\n';
        test_one(inputline, correct_answer);
        ++counter;
    }

    std::cout << "all tests passed\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    run_tests();
}
```

**syntax_tree.hpp** (the iterator is public class of it)

```
#ifndef COMPILER_PARSE_TREE_HPP
#define COMPILER_PARSE_TREE_HPP

#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <map>
#include <iosfwd>
#include <stack>

#include <token.hpp>

namespace markargs
{
    class syntax_tree
    {
        struct node
        {
            markargs::token tk;
            node* left_operand;
            node* right_operand;

            explicit node(const markargs::token& tk_,
                          node* left_operand_ = nullptr,
                          node* right_operand_ = nullptr);
        };

        node* root;

        std::map<std::string, int> operator_precedence;
    public:
        class inorder_iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, token>
        {
            friend syntax_tree;

            node* current_node;
            std::stack<node*> prev_nodes;
            std::map<node*, bool> visited;
        public:
            inorder_iterator();

            inorder_iterator& operator++();
            inorder_iterator operator++(int);

            token& operator*();
            const token& operator*() const;

            token* operator->();
            const token* operator->() const;

            friend bool operator==(const inorder_iterator lhs, const inorder_iterator rhs);
            friend bool operator!=(const inorder_iterator lhs, const inorder_iterator rhs);

        private:
            inorder_iterator(node* current);
            node* find_leftmost_node(node* from);
        };

        template <typename InputIterator>
        syntax_tree(InputIterator first, InputIterator last):
                root(nullptr),
                operator_precedence
                        {
                {"=", 0},
                {"+", 1},
                {"-", 1}
                        }
        {
            std::queue<token> tokens{std::deque<token>{first, last}};
            parse(tokens);
        }

        syntax_tree(const syntax_tree& other) = delete;
        syntax_tree& operator=(const syntax_tree& other) = delete;

        syntax_tree(syntax_tree&& other) noexcept;
        syntax_tree& operator=(syntax_tree&& other) = delete;

        inorder_iterator inorder_begin();
        inorder_iterator inorder_end();

        ~syntax_tree();

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const syntax_tree& tree);
    private:
        void parse(std::queue<token>& tokens);
        void print(std::ostream& os, const node& n) const;
        void recursive_destruct(node* n);
    };
}

#endif //COMPILER_PARSE_TREE_HPP
```

**inorder_iterator.cpp**

```
#include "syntax_tree.hpp"

namespace markargs
{
    syntax_tree::inorder_iterator::inorder_iterator(node* current) :
            current_node(current)
    {
        current_node = find_leftmost_node(current);
        visited[current_node] = true;
    }

    syntax_tree::node* syntax_tree::inorder_iterator::find_leftmost_node(node* from)
    {
        if (from->left_operand != nullptr)
        {
            prev_nodes.push(from);
            return find_leftmost_node(from->left_operand);
        }

        return from;
    }

    syntax_tree::inorder_iterator::inorder_iterator() :
            current_node(nullptr)
    {}

    syntax_tree::inorder_iterator& syntax_tree::inorder_iterator::operator++()
    {
        if (current_node->left_operand != nullptr && !visited[current_node->left_operand])
        {
            prev_nodes.push(current_node);
            current_node = current_node->left_operand;
            return ++*this; //recurse
        }

        if (!visited[current_node])
        {
            visited[current_node] = true;
            return *this;
        }
        else
        {
            //prev_nodes.pop();
            if (current_node->right_operand != nullptr)
            {
                current_node = current_node->right_operand;
                return ++*this;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!prev_nodes.empty())
                {
                    current_node = prev_nodes.top();
                    prev_nodes.pop();
                    return ++*this;
                }
                else
                {
                    current_node = nullptr;
                    return *this;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    syntax_tree::inorder_iterator syntax_tree::inorder_iterator::operator++(int)
    {
        auto copy = *this;
        ++*this;
        return copy;
    }

    const token& syntax_tree::inorder_iterator::operator*() const
    {
        return current_node->tk;
    }

    token& syntax_tree::inorder_iterator::operator*()
    {
        return current_node->tk;
    }

    const token* syntax_tree::inorder_iterator::operator->() const
    {
        return &current_node->tk;
    }

    token* syntax_tree::inorder_iterator::operator->()
    {
        return &current_node->tk;
    }



    bool operator==(const syntax_tree::inorder_iterator lhs, const syntax_tree::inorder_iterator rhs)
    {
        return lhs.current_node == rhs.current_node;
    }

    bool operator!=(const syntax_tree::inorder_iterator lhs, const syntax_tree::inorder_iterator rhs)
    {
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    }
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(compiler)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_library(syntax_analysis syntax_tree.hpp syntax_tree.cpp inorder_iterator.cpp)
target_include_directories(syntax_analysis PUBLIC ../lexical_analysis/)
target_link_libraries(syntax_analysis lexical_analysis)

add_executable(syntax_analysis_tests
        main.cpp
        syntax_tree.hpp
        )
target_link_libraries(syntax_analysis_tests syntax_analysis)
target_include_directories(syntax_analysis_tests PUBLIC ../lexical_analysis/)

configure_file(./input.txt ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/input.txt COPYONLY)
configure_file(./input.txt ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/answers.txt COPYONLY)
configure_file(./failing_input.txt ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/failing_input.txt COPYONLY)

add_test(syntax-analysis-tests syntax_analysis_tests)

add_executable(inorder_iterator_tests
        inorder_iterator_tests.cpp
        syntax_tree.hpp)

target_link_libraries(inorder_iterator_tests syntax_analysis)
```

---

### Design decisions

- Storing previous nodes as `stack`.

  The reason behind this is to make it easier to generalize to any binary tree in the future. If you're familiar with `markarg`s syntax and parser's specifications, at any time any node will only have one leaf left child, thus it could be stored by a pointer or optional.
- Storing visited nodes as `map`.

  I believe I heard it is possible to use stack for this, but I'm not sure. As a result the iterator has insane memory overhead.
- Limiting the iterator to Forward Iterator

  I can't think of the cases Bidirectional Iterator would be useful, so to not elevate complexity I decided to stick with Forward Iterator concept.
- Private constructor

  Since users don't have access to `node`s anyway, public constructor won't make much sense. Public default constructor, which constructs end iterator, is very useful though. End iterator is almost like a functor, since it just checks if the other one set `current_node` to `nullptr`.

---

### Concerns

- Control flow complexity. I believe finding next `node` is expressed in a very non-comprehensive way.
- Memory efficiency. Current design has noticable memory overhead.
- General code quality
- Anything else

---

I know the `iterator` is deprecated, but since tools are still in development for C++17, I decided to stick with C++14.

### Build script

```sh
git clone https://github.com/simmplecoder/markargs.git
cd markargs
git checkout 092a5b37f9ab5af480cb3cb4288869770ac8d42f
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

If you have already cloned it:

```sh
#cd to markargs
git remote add origin https://github.com/simmplecoder/markargs
git fetch origin
git checkout 092a5b37f9ab5af480cb3cb4288869770ac8d42f
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

Comment: Is the build script useful? It forces me to retest the whole thing on my laptop, but I wanted to know if it has any value besides that.

Answer (score 4):

Is there any benefit using a `std::map<node*, bool>` rather than a more simple `std::set`

I would guess that both fulfill the same purpose with the latter beeing more efficient.